# How do you skip back to daylight in Far Cry 5

Tags: far-cry-5

Is there a way to skip night time? I've been playing for a couple of hours without any change. I would like it to become light again.

Comment: Would be nice if that downvote came with an answer :)

Comment: I didn't DV, but I'm assuming the DV is due to lack of apparent effort in researching this yourself.  Stack Exchange doesn't want to duplicate other resources by answering trivial questions (in this case a wikia, or in-game menu system perhaps), so we ask that you at least put *some* effort into figuring it out yourself before posting.  Perhaps you could elaborate on what you've already tried?

Comment: I've been through the settings and I even went to the second Google results page (the first was actually only full of far cry 3 results). I wouldn't ask before looking myself.

Comment: If you searched, your question not show it. All we have to go off of is your question itself; if you don't show research effort there, how are we supposed to know you have?

Comment: @Frank You ask?

Comment: Or, perhaps, you show the effort, and don't get down votes.

Comment: @Frank It's not mandatory to post what you have already tried. Maybe people should stop assuming that I hadn't ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Mandatory" might be a bit strong, but it is [highly reccomended](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that you tell us what you've previously tried when asking a question.  If nothing else, it prevents low-quality answers that suggest things you've already done.

Comment: If you don't want people to assume you haven't researched, then maybe you should actually show that you have.

Comment: I start by assuming the asker has made a best effort to find the answer themselves. I don't think the site would be improved if every question started with, "I searched Google and the menus and the help text and the Wiki and the forums and asked two friends who play."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several threads about this bug on the game's sub-Reddit; [here's one](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/87g025/bug_always_night_in_far_cry_5/) that discussed my particular issue.

John Seed's second forced mission (a mission you're forced to do once you reach a certain **resistance level**) pops you out at a certain time of day and leaves the game stuck there until you do some other mission that forces the time of day to advance.

Faith's first forced mission served that purpose for me.  It's pretty easy to trigger her first mission, too; I don't think you even have to get to her first resistance level circle.  Just wander around in her province and cause a bit of trouble, maybe blow up some property, then wait for one of her hallucinations to appear and try to talk to it.  Walk through the cut-scene.  Problem should be solved.

In total I've now suffered three

## day/night cycle freezes

- After completing John Seed's 2nd forced mission (above)
- After completing **The Admiral**, the last mission in Skylar's quest line
- I don't know what caused the third; I don't think it directly followed any mission.  It may have been the result of quitting out of a Clutch Nixon stunt that I couldn't beat.

## fixes

Any mission that has a cut scene that transports you in time *should* fix the problem (except, of course, for John's mission #2, which does the exact opposite and *causes* the problem):

- Any of Faith's forced missions
- Any of Jacob's forced missions
- Special Delivery
- Testy Festy

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing for many hours and have not seen any mechanism to allow you to manipulate the time of day.  I think cut scenes may take time into consideration, and by coincidence this lead to you experiencing night longer than normal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

By completing the “Testy Festy” missions(all of them) your character will blackout and you will wake up in the morning, reseting the day-night cycle

Comment: It eventually ended, I only recently did this mission. I wouldn't recommend it as the solution